# SSL: certificate subject name does not match target host name

Tags: ssl, unity-game-engine

I have a unity project and contact an API for collecting data.
In the Editor, Android build, iOS build and Windows build everything is working fine. But the build for OSX gives me errors:

```
SSL: certificate subject name 'com-linweb061' does not match target host name 'ava-trix.com'
```

But the common name in my certificate is *.ava-trix.com, as you can see here:
https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html?hostname=https://ava-trix.com

I have no idea what the problem is here. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Are you inside a company network which makes use of ssl interception to sniff encrypted traffic? Or do you have custom hostnames for this particular server in `/etc/hosts` ?

Comment: @DanielW. the "/etc/hosts" save my life ,thanks.when I check /etc/hosts ,fond the record "17*.***.***.*** github.com". every thing right after I del the record

Answer (score 1):

I was using Unity 5.3.5 wich, apparently, has an SSL problem for 32-bit OSX builds. So I created a 64bit version and the problem was gone.

Comment: The real issue was that the site requires [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication). If the client does not support SNI it gets the wrong certificate. Looks like the older build you used had no SNI support while the newer one has.